# MySQL copy database without data in one table

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a database and tables: A,B,C,D. I want to copy a whole structure, but without any data in table B (other tables can have data and this data can be copied). How can I do this?

Is `mysqldump -d -u someuser -p mydatabase A,C,D` correct ?

Because when I tried this it copied my only given tables, without table B. What I want, is that I want to copy everything (data and structure, and so on), but only without data in table B. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in a single mysqldump command.

Mysqldump does have an option `--no-data` so it dumps the table definition (CREATE TABLE) without data (INSERT...). But this applies to all the tables named in the arguments. There's no option for omitting the data from *some* tables.

What you could do is dump tables A,C,D in one command as you are doing, and then subsequently dump table B only, in a second command using `mysqldump --no-data`.

But be careful that no DDL statements happen to any of these four tables between the two dump commands.

Comment: So is it possible to solve the DDL issue? If so, how?

Comment: I mean just don't make schema changes until you're done making the backup.